# Policy on unclued anagrams?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Anagrams are a great component of many puzzles. Recently though, I've been seeing a lot of unclued anagrams - and those make puzzles essentially unsolvable. There are simply too many possibilities for ways to rearrange letters, and even more if you don't say precisely which letters are being rearranged. It's more of "guess what I'm thinking" if you have to figure out which letters to rearrange *and* that you have to rearrange thingswith no clues whatsoever.

Should we mandate that all anagrams are at least hinted at in some way? If so, should we do anything besides downvote questions that contain unclued anagrams?

Comment: Do you have examples? I'm pretty sure I'm totally in agreement with you here, but I can't think of an example of the type of thing you're describing.

Comment: @question_asker [Here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28201/youve-probably-seen-me-naked) , [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28178/rebus-romance-cats-and-a-pen)...

Comment: @question_asker: In addition to Manshu's links, [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23368/what-britney-spears-is-famous-for) and the questions linked there too.

Comment: @manshu and Deusovi: aha!, yeah, ok so: that first one at least says "mixed-up" next to the thing that's supposed to be anagrammed, but yeah, the second one manshu linked to had no indication whatsoever and the ones Deusovi linked/referred to were just utterly inscrutable (both wrt the need to anagram as well as the expected answer). Ugh.

Comment: That said, I honestly have no idea how we would go about making a "policy" to prevent it, at least not any moreso than we could make a policy to prevent "guess what I'm thinking" riddles (or riddles where the clues don't mean what the OP thinks they mean) to begin with. Sorry, I'm not much help here but I share your frustration.

Comment: I agree that the first one manshu linked was fine. "Mixed-up" is a perfectly good anagram indicator, and the text was short enough to be reasonably done, The others, though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems incredibly nitpicky to start mandating this kind of thing.  There are a thousand other minor trends with posted puzzles that we could similarly "mandate" about, but I don't think it would help much, except to make people reticent to post for fear of violating one of a thousand mandates.

If the puzzle doesn't work, it will be downvoted.  That should be enough to discourage people from continuing to do something similar.  If it does work, even with unclued anagrams, there's no issue.

Comment: I appreciate this answer.